# Printing the compilation errors to a file in disk

Tags: java, linux

I am a student of computer science. I am learning java on linux platform ubuntu. While I am compiling a program always I get some compilation error in terminal. I tried to read the error message from terminal. I think reading these error message gives me better understanding about the program/java language itself. So when I recover the error sometimes I would try to read the earlier error message, but the message sometimes removed from the terminal.

So my question is - is there any way to redirecting the error message from terminal to directly to a file.

I am using the fllowing command in ubuntu to compile -

```
$javac MyClass.java > file_name
```

But it prints all the line from the terminal to the **'file_name'**. Is there any way to redirect only the error message?

Thanks.

Comment: $javac MyClass.java >out.log 2> file_name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need

```
$javac MyClass.java 2> file_name
```

which will redirect stderr. You can (instead) redirect stderr to to stdout and then to a file thus:

```
$javac MyClass.java 2>&1 > file_name
```

The above assumes you're using a Bourne-shell type shell (`sh`/`bash`/`ksh`/`zsh`), as opposed to a C-shell variant.

Having said all that, I would (if at all practical) avoid using the command line for general development in favour of an [IDE](http://www.jetbrains.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=983211), which (amongst many other advantages) will tell you a lot more info re. your compilation issues.